# How to change the text of button in other adapter? Android

Tags: android, button, adapter

I have created a adapter and there is a button, and I have a setOnClickListener() in which I want to change the text of a button in other adapter.

How can I do it?

button in adapter 1:

```
accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do nothing but close the dialog
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mAccept = true;
        if (mAccept) {
            count++;
            if(count==1) {
                accept.setText("Dispatching");
                //buyer:requesting---->waiting

            }
            if(count==2) {
                accept.setText("Dispatched");
            }
```

Button in adapter 2:

```
viewHolder.mBuyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

After user click the button in adapter 1,the button becomes "dispatching" and I want the text of button in adapter 2 becomes "waiting".

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Pass your button reference inside adapter.

Comment: **CODE** ??????

Answer (score 0):

When you call your adapter pass the Button variable in it after initiating your button in activity.

for example

Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);

suppose Adapter is your addpter class than

Adapter adapter=new Adapter(button,all_other_parameters_here);

than in Adapter class
in onclick listener use,

button.setText("your text or variable");

OR you can implement on onlicklistner